# javafx responsive design fullscreen

Tags: javafx

I need to reproduce this image in javafx [see Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TvAy.png)

the way i approached this interface is as follows :

- Created a BorderPane layout
- BorderPane.TOP : set inside it a HBOX layout for the menu on top
- BorderPane.Center : set inside it a Pane Layout which contains the the planets ( see image again )

this is end result i got [click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ySiS.png)

Clearly i am doing something wrong here , please clarify to me

this interface is supposed to be FULLSCREEN and responsive

i tried doing the following Controller Code:

```
public class HomeController implements Initializable
{


    @FXML
    private BorderPane borderPane;

    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

       // responsivity
       Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
       Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds();

       Stage stage = Entry.getMainStage();

       stage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
       stage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
       stage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
       stage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());

       // this code gives an error
       borderPane.setBottom(null);
       borderPane.setLeft(null);
       borderPane.setRight(null);
     }



}
```

Comment: Look into `stage.setFullScreen(true);` instead of getting the bounds and you don't need to do `borderPane.set...(null)` you can just leave it out. What is the error or problem with this code that you are trying to resolve?

Comment: @Matt the FullScreen Property is already set in the MAIN class, and there is no errors , it's just that the interface is not responsive while on fullscreen mode , you can see the differences between the two images i provided the first one is the one sent by the designer , the second one is my attempt

Comment: So you have no problems other than design?

Comment: @Matt yes , am I asking this in a wrong way ? if so please redirect me.